# Windows 7 blue screen at start up

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, bsod, adobe-photoshop

I opened my PC and tried to open photoshop , then suddenly my PC restarted itself , so when it booted i tried again to open photoshop. Then i had blue screen and restart.It opened normally,I tried again to open it (after i read why photoshop did that) and bsod appeard again so i did a restart.

And that was the last time it booted properly. Now every time i start my PC when the load screen tries to create the windows flag it goes to bsod and restarts. Tried to repair and i couldn't see the disk for repair and when i pressed load drivers it opened the folder "System 32" and i went to Boot folder to check if there are files and there was 1 folder and 1 file. Is it normal ?

Also we tried for an automatic research for errors and the cause of the error said: Boot manager missing or corrupted.

```
M/B: Gigabyte Z87M-D3H RETAIL
CPU: Intel i7 4790
SSD: TOSHIBA OCZ VT180 240 GB
HDD: Western Digital 2TB RED NAS SATEM
RAM: Asus 2x6GB
```

If you can see my previous question (Title:Windows7 Re-install - SSD not booting - Boot manager does - PC much slower) you will see that i had a problem and is almost a week that i formatted my pc. Before i formatted my pc a week ago i had a problem and the boot folder on windows was empty.Somehow i guess it deleted itself. Is that possible?

Edit: I can't see the cody of the bluescreen it flashes for like 1 second the it restarts. But there was a code after the restart(if i dont select : Start up Windows normally) `0xc000000f` And i restarted it again now the code is: `0xc0000185`

Edit2: I made a bootable USB with the windows7 in it in order to make a try repairing it. I noticed that my SSD (main disk) does not appear :

[image: http://prntscr.com/foyfo3]

Here is the result of the repair:

[image: http://prntscr.com/foyfzz]

Comment: A BSoD always shows an error. We cannot help you unless we know what that error says. Can you edit your post to include that error? It is a text in capitals that could say something like: IRQ_LESS_OR_NOT_EQUAL. Alternatively, write down the stop code, which looks like 0x00000001

Comment: What does your analysis with "windbg" indicate?  Without the analysis or the dmp file we really can't determine the actual cause of this BSOD

Comment: How can i do that analysis ? Remember that i can not boot.

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed it.

I had on: Sata 0 : the HDD (secondary disk)
Sata 1: CD/DVD
Sata 2: SSD (main disk with windows in it)

So i changed them to : Sata 0 : SSD
Sata 1:HDD
Sata 2:CD/DVD

and then i opened my pc , pressed on repair. Took 10 mnts more or less to finish. Then it run again repair (by itself)  that took about a minute.And i could finally boot normally. When i was on desktop there was a message from windows repair with 2 options : Restart now or Restart later. I pressed the Restart now button. It restarted and now it's back to normal.

Also Photoshop works fine.